# ajax post data is not read yii2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii2

I'm trying to read $_POST array posted through AJAX in a controller action using Yii::$app->request->post(), but something strange happens.

jQuery:
`

```
    function renderGridView() {
    var formId = $('#input-field :input[value!=""]');
    // extract values. Make sure to send _csrf token

   $.ajax({
       url: "?r=value-search%2Fsearch", //this one works
       method: 'POST',
       data: {
           searchData: formId.serializeArray(),
       },
       success: function(response) { //JSON array is returned. 
           /*$('#resultGrid').DataTable( {
               data: [
                   response['provider']
                ],
               columns: [
                   response['columns']
                ]
           }); */
           console.log(response);

       }


   })

}
```

`

PHP Controller action:

```
public function actionSearch() {
       $data = \Yii::$app->request->post('searchData');
       $tt; $svalue;
       if(count($data) === 0) {throw new UserException('data is emptry');}

       echo var_dump($data);
    }
```

And here's the issue, the code above works just fine. But when I'm trying to `echo $data` my custom `UserException` 'data is empty' is thrown, instead of PHP's 'trying to pass array as a string', which I'd normally expect. What is causing this? Why does post() behave like this? Is there a technical reason to it?

Comment: `post()` is working good here, your problem is in data you're passing to your action. Simply check what's under `$_POST` @start of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change

```
 data: {
           searchData: formId.serializeArray(),
       },
```

to

```
 data:formId.serialize(),
```

you should use `ActiveForm` to create your form using your model and the names will be automatically assigned to inputs which include the convention `ModelName[field_name]` apart from this you haven't shown your form but in your `action` you are getting the `searchData` in the `post()` array so I assume you have the data being posted as

```
[
  searchData=>[
    field_1=>value,
    field_1=>value,
    field_1=>value,
    field_1=>value,
  ]
]
```